# I get redirected to login page every time i try to access the admin dashboard page

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm logged as Admin( I'm setting a column which has utype="ADM" to verify me as admin in a session).And when I try  to access the admin dashboard page I get redirected to login page  and so on without accessing the dashboard eventually.
This is my AuthAdmin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(session('utype') === 'ADM') {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            session()->flush();
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is my web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified', 'authadmin'])->group(function() {
 Route::get('/admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class)->name('admin.dashboard');
```

I think the issue is mainly focused on the 'authadmin' argument in the route , please provide some tips and help .Thank you

Comment: It's pretty clear from your code that `session('utype') === 'ADM'` is `false`, and you're being logged out via `session()->flush()`, then redirected to `login`. You'll need to debug why that is though... You say "I'm setting a column ...", do you then mean to check via `auth()->user()->utype == 'ADM`? Are you explicitly setting `session()->put('utype', 'ADM')`? Also, your 2nd `return $next($request);` is redundant; you'll never hit that code with your defined `if()` statement.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes sir i mean by it auth()->user()->utype == 'ADM'

Comment: so basically im talking about , access admin dashboard only if auth()->user()->utype=='ADM'

Comment: Yeah, so instead of `if(session('utype') === 'ADM') {`, you'd check `if(auth()->user()->utype == 'ADM') {`, and as long as you're actually logged in (`auth()->user()` will be `null` if you're not), that check should work 

Comment: No problem  Feel free to add a self-answer with your finalized, working code below to properly close this question. Cheers!